# How to color a tag in a math equation?

Tags: math-mode, color, amsmath, tag

I have a math equation with a `\tag` operator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

This is my favorite equality:
\begin{align*}
    \color{red}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}.\tag{E1}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

**I would like to color the tag (E1) in red.**

What I did is I added `\tag{\textcolor{red}{E1}}` but this only colored the E1 without the parentheses.

Comment: You could use `\tag*` and add the () manually to it

Comment: You could write either `\tag*{\textcolor{red}{(E1)}}` (as already suggested by @daleif) or `\tag*{\color{red}(E1)}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newtagform{red}{\color{red}(}{)}
\usetagform{red}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
   \color{red} \sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}.\tag{E1}
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

You can redefine the tag

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

> CODE with newcommand

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\TAG}[1]{\tag*{\textcolor{red}{(#1)}}}
\begin{document}

This is my favorite equality:
\begin{align*}
    \color{red}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}.\TAG{E1}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

> CODE based on the comments by [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif) and [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

This is my favorite equality:
\begin{align*}
\color{red}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}.
\tag*{\textcolor{red}{(E1)}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Approved all the answers and the question.